# Ubuntu Disk isn't showing up at Boot

Tags: macos, disk-utility, unix, usb

I recently installed ubuntu on a flash drive, following all of the instructions on the ubuntu website.

When I started up my mac, it didn't appear in the boot menu. Has this happened to anyone else here booting their thumb drives onto their macs? If so, what did you do to fix this?

(I asked this on the Ubuntu forums as well, but I thought that it would be relevant here as well)

Comment: Have you used the right kind of partitioning? (apple part ion map)

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX What do you mean? And if I didn't, then how could I format my usb drive with the os on it still intact?

Comment: Nope, but under the disk utility "partition" tab of the drive, click options, and pick apple partition map if u'd like it to be bootable by macs

Comment: What about GUID partition table?

Comment: Sorry, the APM was for PPC macs, since you have and intel mac, you should use GUID

Comment: Hm. How can I do this exactly?

Comment: under the disk utility "partition" tab of the drive, click options

Comment: when you insert your flash-drive and start up your mac hold the "alt" key after the chime (when the light blue screen appears) to see all boot options (it may take a few seconds). is your stick listed there as a bootable option ?!

Answer (score 1):

hold option at the sound of the chime.